# Parsing With NSXML Parser Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, nsxmlparser

I am trying to parse the following information from xml in Cocoa.

```
<level>
  <entity>
    <name>red</name>
    <id>0</id>
    <body>false</body>
    <x>0.0</x>
    <y>0.0</y>
    <rotation>0.0</rotation>
  </entity>
```

Here is what i have so far from following the nsxml parser guide by apple.

```
NSString* currentElement;


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

currentElement = elementName;

}



- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

 if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"name"]){
     NSLog(@"Name found: %@", string);
 }

 }
```

In my found character method it logs the statement but the only thing returning is "Name found:  " and the rest is blank.

Am i doing this correctly to get the following tags in my xml? I would like to extract each tag.

for example:

```
NSString* name = THE_NAME;
int x = [THE_X_VALUE, intValue];
```

etc.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: "the only thing returning is "found characters: "" - do you mean the NSLog only prints "Name found:"?

Comment: Sorry. Yes. It only prints "Name Found:    "

Comment: You know that method may not contain all the characters and may be called multiple times so you really want to accumulate those characters in an `NSMutableString`?

Comment: Could you show me what you mean exactly?

Comment: @userXXX Aren't there multiple calls to this method? If there is, does all of them really log only an empty string?

Comment: No some of them log the strings, but some of them dont. I dont understand why some are returning blank

Comment: @userXXX for the reason I explained in my second comment.

Comment: So your suggestion is add them to an array? and then what? Could you show me an example?

Comment: @userXXX append them to a mutable string like this: `[someMutableString appendString:string];`.

Comment: Oh i see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: This probably won't answer your question, but might make it easier to do what you're doing: https://github.com/boredzo/PRHXMLParser

Answer (score 0):

NSXMLParser is one of those classes that sounds good on paper, but drives you insane when you actually start to use it. If you really want to continue on this joyless path, implement parser:didStartElement: and then pray that parser:foundCharacters: delivers the goods. 
In my experience, NSXMLParser is like a big toddler who smashes the puzzle and then hands you the pieces one by one. That seems like a great at first: "Oh look, I've got a piece! And another one! And one more!" but soon you find yourself bewildered: "Oh look, I've got 5.0! Now, was that the rotation or the y coordinates?" Who knows? Not NSXMLParser, that's for sure.

As for the last line of code: to extract the numeric value of a string, NSDecimalNumber is very handy.

```
if([currentElement isEqualToString:@"x"]){
    NSDecimalNumber *dec = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithString:string];
    CGFloat x = dec.floatValue;
}
```